# Get document attachment list in qweb report Odoo

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-10, qweb, odoo-view

I am using qweb reports to generate a document which should have associated attachments using the `document` module of Odoo. But I don't know how to display the list of attachments associated to a document in the qweb/pdf report.

Please note that I am not asking to store a document as attachment. Just to display the list of current attachments in a report.

Do you know how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve that problem using [computed fields](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/reference/orm.html#computed-fields) in a relationship one2many.

this make the magic:

```py
attachment_ids = fields.One2many(comodel_name="ir.attachment", inverse_name="res_id", compute="_add_attachment")
@api.multi
def _add_attachment(self):
    self.attachment_ids = self.env['ir.attachment'].search([('res_model','=','document'),('res_id','=',self.id)])
```